# Is SBT 0.13.5 supported on Docker/Dokku images?

Tags: playframework, sbt, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

I am experimenting with DigitalOcean's droplets. I have created a Docker/Dokku image and I'm pushing my Play!Framework 2.3.1 app. Unfortunately it won't be built because sbt 0.13.5 is not supported!

```
       Play 2.x - Scala app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.6...done
 !     Error, SBT version 0.13.5 not supported
```

How can I fix this? I think I need to update the buildstep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to update Dokku's Buildstep. I managed to thanks to Dokku's readme and [this](http://blog.zefwebdesign.co.uk/dokku-laravel-digital-ocean/) blog post. Yay!

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed this myself today. I first went and updated docker by

```
cd ~/dokku
git pull origin master
sudo make install
```

After that finishes, I updated Dokku's Buildstep. 
First I deleted the Buildstep image

```
docker images
```

You get a list of images. Find this one

```
progrium/buildstep           latest              {IMAGE ID}        11 minutes ago      1.048 GB
```

Copy the Image ID and delete it

```
docker rmi {IMAGE ID}
```

Then clone the Buildstep git project

```
git clone https://github.com/progrium/buildstep.git
make build
```

That will create the new docker image (that will take a few minutes though).
You can now deploy any project that uses SBT version 0.13.5!

(When upgrading a Play! 2.2.1 application to 2.3.1, I had to delete the project first, otherwise it wouldn't push!)

Comment: I didn't need to delete the existing image, nor to delete the project first in order to push..? Maybe I was using an already newer docker/dokku combo.

Comment: I needed to do a "play clean" command on my localbox before it would run locally, so I'm sure it was just something to do with temp files or something like that. There is a good chance you didn't need to delete the buildstep image, but I wasn't sure when I did it!